# Using a delegate in class field?

Tags: c#

Sometimes I see something similar to this inside a C# class:

```
private CultureInfo _culture = () => Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

I tried this but it does not compile ... My questions are:

1. How should I change this to compile?
2. What is the difference between this code and:

   `private CultureInfo _culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;`

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 3):

If you use

```
private Func<CultureInfo> _culture = () => Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

you get the current culture info for the actual thread at the actual moment.

Istead if you do

```
private CultureInfo _culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

you always get the culture info from the thread in which it was initialized at the time it was initialized.

As an improvement use a property to encapsulate `_culture` after using the function initialisation:

```
private CultureInfo Culture 
{
    get { return _culture(); }
}
```

This gives you a member variable like usage.

Answer (score 1):

use this..

```
private Func<CultureInfo> _culture = () => Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
```

Comment: But why is this often used instead of just declaring the field?

Comment: Using Action and Func delegates save space and reduce the size of large methods and reduces redundant code, give a nice signature to the code segment and can easily be promoted to a method if need be.